# Cannot open include file "jni.h", No such file or directory exists

Tags: path, java-native-interface, compiler-errors, fatal-error

I am implementing the simple JNI example , as given in

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html

At the second last step, when the C source is being compiled,

the following command is used:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21> cl -IC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\include -IC:\Program Files\Java\jdl1.6.0_21\include\win32 -MD -LD Callbacks.c -FeCallbacks.dll
```

I get the following error:

> "Cannot open include file "jni.h", No such file or directory exists."

But `jni.h` does exist in java/jdk1.6.0_21/include folder.

How can I remove this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the path contain spaces u need to enclose the path inside "" like
cl -IC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\includ e -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdl1.6.0_21\include\win32" -MD -LD Callbacks.c -FeCallb acks.dll

Answer (score 1):

If the path contains spaces then you must have to quote the path . In my case the command is as follows :

```
cl -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\include\win32" -LD HelloWorldImp.c -Fehello.dll
```

Hope it helps .